# using spring-mvc AbstractExcelView with an already created document

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use AbstractExcelView to serve an XLS document that I create on a server. Is there a way I can use this with an already constructed workbook? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractExcelView;


public class ValidationErrorsView  extends AbstractExcelView {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map arg0, HSSFWorkbook workbook,     
 HttpServletRequest arg2, HttpServletResponse arg3) 
    throws Exception {

    final String toprocess = "myfile.xls";
    final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(toprocess);
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook (is);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an `AbstractExcelView` to serve an existing document.

- If the document is in the public folders of your webapp, users can download it as a static file.
- If it's under `WEB-INF`, you can forward request to it using `request.getRequestDispatcher(fileName).forward(request, response)`.
- If it's an arbitrary file, you should open the file and copy its content into `response.getOutputStream()`

However, don't forget to set the right content type: `response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");`

Comment: Because I am storing the file in a non-web accessible loction, I am just copying it to the outputstream and setting the appropriate content type. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ValidationErrorsView extends AbstractExcelView {

    public ValidationErrorsView() {
        super();
        setUrl("/WEB-INF/templates/1.1");
    }

    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map model, HSSFWorkbook workbook,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

    }
}
```

"1.1" is existing excel file name.

workbook - created from 1.1.xls file.